# YouTube fullscreen background autoplay not working in YTplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayer

> I am using YTplayer plugin for fullscreen youtube player in
>   [this-website](http://judefly.com/) Get inspired tab!

- I have provided code below with usefull links! I think the code is correct!
- Player is working if we click on the play control on hover at bottom of video player!(image below)!
- Please help me to sort out why autoplay is not working?
- where my code is having error?

---

[image: player]

---

#### Useful Links >>

---

[**https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer**](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer)

[**http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-YTPlayer/**](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-YTPlayer/)

[**http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/YTPlayer.html**](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/YTPlayer.html)

---

#### Here is the code >>

---

```
<a class="player" id="player" data-property="{
               videoURL: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9fgbuH0_RI&feature=youtu.be',
               containment:'#videobg',
               autoPlay: true,
               optimizeDisplay: true,
               showControls: true,
               startAt: 0,
               opacity: 1,
               ratio: '4/3', 
               addRaster: false }"></a>

            <div id="videobg" class="section-divider white-text videobg" data-scroll-index="4">
                <div class="pattern-overlay"></div>
                <div class="triangle-right"></div>

                <div class="container extra-padding">
                    <div class="col-md-5 extra-padding">
                        <h1>INNOVATING THROUGH TRAVEL</h1>
                        <p>Travel is more than the seeing of sights; it is a change that goes on, deep and permanent, in the ideas of living.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

### solution

- Use Latest version of the java script for ytplayer.

Comment: `Please help me to sort out issue!` what's the issue ?

Comment: Autoplay not working! Clear in title of question!

Comment: don't you think the problem is from the repo pupunzi and not from the API ?

Comment: Dont know! Just Stuck at this point!

Comment: Well autoplay from the API works like a charm, live example http://jsbin.com/cocatuta/26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Seem the problem is from the repo **jquery.mb.YTPlayer**.
If we look at the issue https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/issues/49

Be sure you have the last version of the repo.

---

After reading the doc from the repo, try to replace : `autoPlay: true,` by `autoplay: true,`

Final code :

```
<a class="player" id="player" data-property="{
   videoURL: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9fgbuH0_RI&feature=youtu.be',
   containment:'#videobg',
   autoplay: true,
   optimizeDisplay: true,
   showControls: true,
   startAt: 0,
   opacity: 1,
   ratio: '4/3', 
   addRaster: false }"></a>

<div id="videobg" class="section-divider white-text videobg" data-scroll-index="4">
    <div class="pattern-overlay"></div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>

    <div class="container extra-padding">
        <div class="col-md-5 extra-padding">
            <h1>INNOVATING THROUGH TRAVEL</h1>
            <p>Travel is more than the seeing of sights; it is a change that goes on, deep and permanent, in the ideas of living.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doc : https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki

Comment: oh ya seen the new link! wait

Comment: Thank You very much! Just replaced new jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js! and it worked!